# Is it possible to set column name dynamically on a dojo grid?

Tags: grid, dojo, dojox.grid

Is there any way to set a dynamic name for column header, for example in a formatter function!?

I'll have a popup menu on the grid and depending on the chosen option it should change the name displayed in the column header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its quite easy if you use dojo.query

```
var grid = dijit.byId('myGridId'),  NewHeader = "Foo Bar Text Content";
var columnHeaderNodes = dojo.query(
              '.dojoxGridHeader table th',
               grid.viewsHeaderNode)
var nthColumn = 12;
// if has child and its not a textnode - this may happen
// when there is a listener (dnd, click) attached for sorting etc.
if(columnHeaderNodes[nthColumn].firstChild && columnHeaderNodes[nthColumn].firstChild.nodeType != 3) 
    tgt = columnHeaderNodes[nthColumn].firstChild;
else tgt = columnHeaderNodes[nthColumn];
tgt.innerHTML = NewHeader;
```

Comment: Great! That was really helpful, exactly what I meant with my question. Thank you!

Comment: @mschr can you please help me with this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826506/set-dojox-grid-datagrid-header-column-width-dynamically