# Avoid decimal values in dijit/form/HorizontalSlider

Tags: javascript, slider, dojo

In `dijit/form/HorizontalSlider` on change I am getting values in a textbox. The values are decimal, like `51.66777777`.  I want only `51`.

```
<div id="horizontalSlider"></div>
<input type="text" id="sliderValue" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox" style="width:190px;" onkeyup="getSliderTxtBoxValue();">

var slider = new HorizontalSlider({
                    name: "horizontalSlider",
                    value: 1,
                    minimum: 1,
                    maximum: 500,
                    discreteValues: 10,
                    intermediateChanges: true,
                    style: "width:200px;",
                    onChange: function(value){
                        dom.byId("sliderValue").value = value;
                    }
                }, "horizontalSlider");
```

> #### See Also:
>
> http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/HorizontalSlider.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you ever seen Spinal Tap?  This one goes to 11!

Here is the code that will work:

```
value: 0,
minimum: 0,
maximum: 500,
discreteValues: 11,
```

You want 11 because you want 11 discrete values:

`0,50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500`

I created a **[fiddle for this problem](http://jsfiddle.net/JhPcj/1/).**

Comment: got it thanks. can you tell me how discreteValues: 11 is avoiding decimal values?

Comment: It's a classic programmer saying, ["Programmers are always off by one"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).  In this case it would be much cooler if the widget specified a increment instead of a number of discrete values.  Increment by 50 makes much more sense.  One thing to note is that `500/9=55.555`.  That is your increment if you use `discreteValues: 10` because you need to include the zero as a value.